# ObjC AES128 Encryption with binary key

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt data with AES128, I get right output with key being treated as text string, but only garbage trying to treat key as binary.

Implementation I'm using is this:

```
- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1];
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr));

[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

NSLog(@"keyPtr: %s", keyPtr);


size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0x00,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                      NULL , [self bytes], dataLength, buffer, bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free(buffer);
return nil;
}
```

The encryption in [this online tool example](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/run/?inputType=frm-text&text=messagetocrypt&text_type=plain&function=aes&mode=ecb&key=FAFBFCFDFEF1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFB&key_type=hex&do=form-submit&encrypt=do) is exactly what I need.

With my implementation I get same a correct encryption for plaintext key, but I can't find a way to treat key as hex.
Tried to modify the code above to get key as NSData but is not working, I get only garbage after encryption.

I searched and didn't found an answer on this specific subject, hope I did it right, TIA :)

Comment: As far as I understand yeah, it should use the key as binary. You're right, I will edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: The above code is very different from the linked web tool. The key size and mode are different, so you shouldn't expect a match. The web tool is very insecure, so it would be preferable not to copy it. (Your code is also very insecure, but slightly less than the web tool which is really broken in its default configuration.) Do you really need to match that web tool? What are you trying to encrypt, and what kind of key do you have to encrypt it?

Comment: What is weird is that the code I'm using return matching result (same as that tool) with ASCII key, different with NSData binary key. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you mean "Hex", which is a string representation.  I think you mean "binary", so simply provide the key as `NSData`:

```
- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSData *)key {
    NSAssert([key length] >= kCCKeySizeAES256, @"Key too short");
    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    NSMutableData *encrypted = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:bufferSize];

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0x00,
                                          [key bytes], kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL , [self bytes], dataLength,
                                          [encrypted mutableBytes], bufferSize,
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        [encrypted setLength:numBytesEncrypted];
        return encrypted;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Note: your code contained one memory leak and I think you weren't returning the encrpypted data properly.

Comment: I would recommend verifying that the key is exactly the length desired. If an unexpectedly-long key is passed, you shouldn't quietly truncate; it should be an error. I don't believe the original code has a memory leak; the `malloc` gets adopted by the `NSData` or is freed. (His code is insecure, and doesn't actually match the linked website, but that's a different matter…) It's worth noting that this answer doesn't set an IV, and so is fairly weak at the start of the message.

Comment: @trojanfoe:  Thanks for your fixed code. Just a thing to fix: NSAssert([key length] >= kCCKeySizeAES256, @"Key too short") should be NSAssert([key length] >= kCCKeySizeAES128, @"Key too short"); I tried and I still get another result, that tool sucks indeed, but I need to match that. I'm passing key and message in fixed length so shouldn't be a problem, key is fixed (16bytes of course) and message is always 32bytes (i'm padding it to 32bytes with a custom padding before encryption, that's why I use 0x00 for AES128 padding parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Solved modifying trojanfoe's code, thanks a lot!

```
- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSData *)key {
NSAssert([key length] >= kCCKeySizeAES128, @"Key too short");
NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, ccPKCS7Padding,
                                      [key bytes], kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                      NULL , [self bytes], dataLength, buffer, bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free(buffer);
return nil;
}
```

With this I get same output as that online tool.
I know it's potentially insecure, thanks for the advice, but I need it for my own use only, will not being distributed so only thing I need is it to work properly and output same result as that tool.

Thanks everybody!